# I can't change the value upload_max_filesize in php.ini

Tags: php

i'm using

```
post_max_size = 9M
upload_max_filesize = 8M
max_execution_time = 1000
max_input_time = 1000
```

to change the value in php.ini and put it at the root of my site. But it is not changing.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi leo are you using a local server?

Comment: you can also use `ini_set()` in your script

Comment: Did you restart apache?

Comment: Exactly my thought @Mihai thats why i wanted to if he was running a local server for a start

Comment: No, i'm using a web server // Saurabh, thanks, i'll try it // No, i didn't, i'll try it too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) to figure out what ini file is being loaded:

[image]

- Ensure you're editing the correct file
- Ensure there is nothing below it in the file that would overwrite the previous `upload_max_filesize`

Comment: I did this, and it appears that folder "/usr/lib". but i'cant find this folder.

Comment: Try the `/lib` folder instead. You may have a symlink that's redirecting `/usr/lib` to another folder.

Comment: I checked it, and the file is the right one, but still the phpinfo.php file shows a different value